# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getName' of undefined(anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

```
 <script>  
    var Employee = new function(name)
    {
     this.name=name;
    }
    Employee.prototype.getName = function()
    {
      return this.name;
    }

    var PermanenetEmployee = new function(annualsalary)
    {
    this.annualsalary=annualsalary;
    }
    var employee = new Employee("rahul");
    PermanenetEmployee.prototype = employee;
    var pe = new PermanenetEmployee(5001);
    document.write(pe.getName());



    </script>
```

i am implementing inheritance in java script. From this code i want to print employee name like "rahul".But i am getting error in this like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getName' of undefined(anonymous function).How to resolve this error?

```
Employee.prototype.getName = function()
        {
          return this.name;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
var Employee = new function(name)
// ------------^^^
{
 this.name=name;
}
```

(And the same for `PermanenetEmployee`.)

You don't want `new` there. `new` **calls** the function. You want to do that later, as you have when assigning to `employee`.

---

Note that the way you're setting up inheritance between them is an anti-pattern. To make `PermanenetEmployee` correctly "subclass" `Employee`, do this:

```
PermanenetEmployee.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
PermanenetEmployee.prototype.constructor = PermanenetEmployee;
```

not

```
var employee = new Employee("rahul");
PermanenetEmployee.prototype = employee;
```

...and then have `PermanenetEmployee` accept `name` and pass it to `Employee`:

```
var PermanenetEmployee = function(name, annualsalary) {
    Employee.all(this, name); // <====
    // ...
};
```

...or better use, use ES2015 ("ES6") `class` (transpiling if you need to, for instance with Babel).

Here's a correct setup. I've also fixed the typo in `PermanenetEmployee`:

```js
var Employee = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};
Employee.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
};

var PermanentEmployee = function(name, annualSalary) {
    Employee.call(this, name);
    this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
};

// Set up subclass
PermanentEmployee.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
PermanentEmployee.prototype.constructor = PermanentEmployee.prototype;

PermanentEmployee.prototype.getAnnualSalary = function() {
    return this.annualSalary;
};

// Using
var pe = new PermanentEmployee("Rahul", 5001);
console.log(pe.getName());
console.log(pe.getAnnualSalary());
```

And with ES2015:

```js
class Employee {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class PermanentEmployee extends Employee {
    constructor(name, annualSalary) {
        super(name);
        this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
    }

    getAnnualSalary() {
        return this.annualSalary;
    }
}

// Using
var pe = new PermanentEmployee("Rahul", 5001);
console.log(pe.getName());
console.log(pe.getAnnualSalary());
```

Again, note that you need to transpile if you want to use that syntax in the wild (for now).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can get inheritance to work in JS, I am using this pattern.

First declare the base prototype:

```
Employee = function () {
};
Employee.prototype = {
    getName: function () {}
};
```

And then the prototype that inherits the base:

```
PermanentEmployee = function () {
    Employee.call(this);
};

PermanentEmployee.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
PermanentEmployee.constructor = PermanentEmployee;

PermanentEmployee.prototype.foo = function() {}
```